programacion php con tunel ssh
Soy nuevo en  programación . Necesito programar una conexión hacia una base de datos postgres en php pero con tunel ssh.
He visto poca información al respecto.
Tengo la ip donde se encuentra la base de datos postgres 10.1.1.1., con el nombre de la base "Tickets", usuario "jaime.sanchez" y contraseña "123456".
Tambien tengo la ip de ssh 10.1.1.2,, usuario "jaime.sanchez" y como metodo de autentificación un archivo .pem
Que programación debo de hacer para conectarme a la base de datos en php.? Método PDO.
Gracias de antemano.

Pero, ¿cuál es el motivo por el que quieres usar un túnel para la conexión?

Tendrías que hacer el túnel ssh en otro proceso, por ejemplo por línea de comando:
ssh -f -N -i ~/.ssh/tu-archivo.pem jaime.sanchez@10.1.1.2 -L 5433:10.1.1.1:5432

corriendo ese comando, te conectas con PDO a tu local usando 127.0.0.1 y el puerto 5433, que gracias al túnel están apuntando a 10.1.1.1:5432
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$dbuser = 'jaime.sanchez';
$dbport = '5433';
$dbpass = '123456';
$dbname = 'Tickets';

